# Write a user to Firestore after new user registration

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

this is my function:

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 exports.newUserToFirestore = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    var current = new Date().toString();
    var email = user.email;
    var nameIndex = email.indexOf('@');
    var nameUser = email.substring(0,nameIndex);
    console.log(user.uid + ',' + nameIndex + ',' + nameUser)
    firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc()
    .set({
        userId: user.uid,
        email: user.email,
        name: nameUser,
        creationDate: current
        })
  });
```

Deploy worked, but when I create a new User, i get `Function execution took 9 ms, finished with status: 'error'` in the Firebase functions Logs.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to return a promise, so u can try add a return before firebase.firestore

Comment: Seems like your console.log is not even reached. Can you console.log the email ?

Comment: How do you define `firebase`? Are you showing the entire code from your `index.js` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cloud Functions, if you want to interact with the other Firebase services, you need to use the Admin SDK. As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app), you need to load the `firebase-admin` module, and initialize an admin app instance.

In your case, it seems that you don't use the `firebase-admin` module and don't initialize an admin app instance.

In addition, as @SomeoneSpecial commented, in order to correctly manage the CF life cycle you need to return a promise when all the asynchronous work is completed (more detail [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)). Since the `set()` method returns a Promise, just return it.

So you need to modify your code as follows:

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp();

 exports.newUserToFirestore = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    var current = new Date().toString();
    var email = user.email;
    var nameIndex = email.indexOf('@');
    var nameUser = email.substring(0,nameIndex);
    console.log(user.uid + ',' + nameIndex + ',' + nameUser)

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc()  // <= See that we use admin here
    .set({
        userId: user.uid,
        email: user.email,
        name: nameUser,
        creationDate: current
        })
  });
```

---

Note that a common practice when creating a user document in Firestore is to use the user ID as the Firestore document ID. This way it is easier to query this doc from the front-end.